# How to get all the values of el-rate element embedded in a el-table

Tags: vue.js

```
<el-table-column label="id" width="80">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
        <span style="margin-left: 10px">{{(currentPage-1) * pageSize +TableMovie.indexOf(scope.row) +1 }} </span>
    </template>
</el-table-column>
<el-table-column label="name" width="120">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
        <span style="margin-left: 10px">{{ scope.row.movie }}</span>
    </template>
</el-table-column> 
<el-table-column label="Rate" width="120">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
        <el-rate
          v-model="scope.row.evaValue"
          @change="handleRate(scope.row.id,scope.row.evaValue)"
          show-text>
        </el-rate>
```

I want to collect the rate for each movie. When user clicks the submit button, the database will be updated correspondingly.
I would like to know how to collect the rate, for the `v-model` for `el-rate` is a single value.

Comment: What is problem with your current code?

Comment: there is no problem with this code, just to show what I want to do. The problem is if I want to collect the rate for all the movie, I don't know how to do it. in the code as you can see, the v-model of rate-element is a single variable, I don't know how to collect the rate value as a list......